# What to use instead of string.Format with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for just a single placeholder?

Tags: c#

I heard that there is no need to use string.Format with a single placeholder.

For example, how can I change the following code accordingly, considering `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`,

```
string myString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", myMethod());
```

`myMethod()` returns a `string` object.

Btw, I modified some existing code like the following  to have one place holder only

```
string myString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", myMethod1(), myMethod2());
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want in `myString` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What does `myMethod` return?

Comment: Certain types (like int, decimal and so on) provide overload of ToString() which accepts format provider. If myMethod() returns such type - you can just use myMethod().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture). And if that type does _not_ provide such overload of ToString() - there is high chance culture is irrelevant for its string representation.

Comment: If it returns string, what exactly you are trying to do? It's already a string and `String.Format` will not do anything with it.

Comment: If the method returns a string there is no reason to use `String.Format()`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen by formatting a string based on a culture?  Typically that would be used for a numeric or date or time type...

Comment: @DanField I want to preserve the original code with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`  as much as possible.

Comment: @Tim what does that mean? Preserver which code? The result is already a string, just use it. The only thing that `String.Format()` does is create yet another temporary string

Comment: @Evk Do I need to preserve `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @Tim it's a string already. Formatting it won't have any effect. You don't need to preseve `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, you need to discared `String.Format` entirely and simply use the return value `string myString=myMethod1();`

Comment: You pass culture to String.Format because you want to _convert_ your arguments to string using certain culture. For example dates are formatted differently in US and Russia, numbers too (some use comma as separator, others dot). Strings obviously do not need to be formatted like this.

Comment: @Evk why is a single string not needed to be formatted like this, If the original code use ` CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: In the original code there were two arguments. If both of them were strings - there was no need to pass InvariantCulture there, it has no effect. However if one was string but other was not - passing culture makes sense to format that other non-string argument. For string arguments it will have no effect. When you changed your code and only one argument left, which is already string - you can remove string.Format completely and just use `myMethod()`.

Comment: @Evk in the original code, both `myMethod1()` and `myMethod2()` return `string` objects. Did it make sense to use `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with my thoughts about this.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on my comment. For each argument, `String.Format` checks if object implements `IFormattable` interface, which looks like this:

```
public interface IFormattable
{
    string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider);
}
```

If argument implements it - `String.Format` will call that `ToString` and pass your formatter there. Otherwise, it will call regular `ToString` without providing formatter.

A lot of types (both .NET Framework and third party) implement this interface, such as all numeric types, date time and so on. If your `myMethod()` returns type that implements `IFormattable` - just call `ToString` yourself (most such types for convenience also implement `ToString` with one parameter, which is not part of `IFormattable` interface):

```
myMethod().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If type does not implement such interface - `String.Format` will also do nothing useful for it (will not use formatter you passed) - so nothing is lost.

UPDATE: since your argument is string - there is no need to pass formatter to `String.Format` and in your specific case use `String.Format` at all. Formatter is used to *convert* object to string using specific rules, and string is well already a string.

In your old code there was multiple arguments, some of them might not be strings and then passing culture makes sense. Also someone might be on a safe side and decide to pass culture even if all arguments are strings, because who knows what will happen later - someone might add more arguments, or current arguments might change types, and of course when this happens no one will change `String.Format` to accept invariant culture. So in general such approach does make sense.

However, when only one argument left and that is string - there is no sense any more for such complications - just remove `String.Format` statement completely and replace with `myMethod()`.